# Append a plus sign before positive numbers?

Tags: python, printf

I'm printing floats trimmed to 3 digits after the zero, and I'd like to know if I can conditionally append a <kbd>+</kbd> before positive numbers, so I get

```
+0.005
```

for a positive change and

```
-0.005
```

for a negative change. Is this easily possible from within printf?

Comment: When you tried it, what did you learn?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, just use a '+' in the format specifier.

Ex:

```
>>> "{0:+.03f}".format(1.23456)
'+1.235'
```

Comment: ^ Correct arguments order is `format('%+.03f', 1.23456)`

Comment: @dreikanter, not in python

Comment: `>>> "{0:+.03f}".format(0.0)
'+0.000'`
Positive 0?

Answer (score 6):

There's a `+` modifier for numbers. Eg. "%+d" or "%+f"

Comment: Example: `print("%+d" % 0)` . 

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a better answer would be...

```
>>> for number in [-42, 0, 1, +13]:
...     print("%+d" % number if number != 0 else "0")
... 
-42
0
+1
+13
>>>
```

Or simply...

```
>>> number = 13
>>> number_str = "%+d" % number if number != 0 else "0"
>>> print(number_str)
+13
>>>
```

**EXTRA:** If you want to reverse the sign of an integer...

```
>>> number = -13
>>> number_str = "%+d" % -number if number != 0 else "0"
>>> print(number_str)
+13
>>>
```

**Thanks!**